# If the same value is being printed on the console before calling axios, why is it that a different value gets sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form field that has the following generic autocomplete:

```
      <generic-autocomplete
        v-model='c.heuristicId'
        v-on:change='heuristicSelected(i, $event)'
        label='Fuente de datos'
        :apiFunction='heuristicsFetchFunction'
        :disabled='disabled'/>
```

When saving the form and sending it with this field in blank `heuristicId`gets sent as `null`which is what is desired.

However, when selecting a value from the generic autocomplete and then deleting it, `heuristicId`gets sent with the id of the previously selected value.

Inside the function that calls axios I'm logging `console.log("heuristicId to be sent: " + campaign.heuristicId);`and `undefined`gets logged in both scenarios.

EDIT: After inquiring a little bit more I believe that the error might be in one of `<generic-autocomplete/>`'s computed properties:

```
  isValid: function () {
    // this checks that the name in display equals the object selected in
    // memory so no invalid labels are displayed while a valid object is 'selected'
    let vc = this
    let result = false
    if (vc.object) {
      result = vc.objectName === vc.object.name
      console.log('generic-autocomplete#isValid', result)
    }
    return result
  }
```

An empty `vc.object`will return a `false`result and I haven't been able to satisfactorily handle that.

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere? And you can also remove irrelevant code from your question so that people can obtain better the wrong part.

Comment: @Asqan please check the new edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After logging a really complex control flow I finally got to the point where I knew which properties I had to mutate. However, it turns out that in Vue 2 mutating inline properties is an anti-pattern. The capability of mutating inline props was deprecated from the previous Vue version in order to be consistent with the library's fully reactive paradigm. So what happens is that if you try to mutate an inline property, when the component re-renders, such property will be set back to its default (or previous) value.

**This is solved by adding a computed property that's a copy from the property that you want to mutate.**

```
//Somewhere else in the code the property is defined
property: null

//Add the computed property
data: function () {
    return {
      mutableProperty: this.property,
    }
}
```